# FFMPEG .mov to .mp4 convertion failure

Tags: android, ios, video, ffmpeg

I'm converting .mov and .mp4 to .mp4 with FFMPEG to play them on iOS and Android devices. Mp4 from Android is converting properly and playing on both devices iPhone and Android. But iPhone's .mov result is strange. It's playing on iPhone and Android 4. But when I'm trying to open this video with Photo app (Android 5, 6) it outputs unsupported video message.

FFMPEG command:

```
ffmpeg -i app/data/storage/68/fa/39/68fa392b-df25-4622-93ab-cf9bf1253f63 \
       -y -b:a 128k -ac 2 -acodec libfdk_aac -b:v 300k -vcodec libx264 \
       -filter:v scale=w=320:h=trunc(ow/a/2)*2 -vprofile baseline \
       -movflags faststart -f mp4 \
       app/data/storage/68/fa/39/68fa392b-df25-4622-93ab-cf9bf1253f63.mp4
```

ffprobe with output file:

```
ffprobe version N-80026-g936751b Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      55. 24.100 / 55. 24.100
  libavcodec     57. 42.100 / 57. 42.100
  libavformat    57. 36.100 / 57. 36.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 45.100 /  6. 45.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '68fa392b-df25-4622-93ab-cf9bf1253f63.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.36.100
  Duration: 00:00:00.65, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 297 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x568, 178 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Comment: The above cli command creates `*.mp4` file which works fine? Can you show how you generate the `*.mov`

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark this question as solved. To do so, please just self-accept your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved and it was in file name with colons.